# How to define $E(X)$ when X is a random variable from the sample space to an infinite-dimensional topological vector space?

Tags: probability, functional-analysis, probability-theory, probability-distributions, geometric-probability

Let $V$ be an infinite-dimensional vector space with a topology. For simplicity, we can assume $V$ is a Banach space. Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ be a probability space. Let $X:\Omega \to V$ be a random variable (= measurable map, i.e. a map that pulls each open set into $V$ a measurable set in $\mathcal{F}$. How do we define $E(X)$ assuming it exists?

So, we need to define the integral $\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)dP(\omega)$ in this setting: how to do that?

The problem is: $X(\omega)$ has an infinite expression, may be an infinite sum expression, assuming a countable Schauder basis for $V$. But this expression will depend on $\omega$. I cannot get around that. Is there any specific case of infinite dimensional $V$ where things will be relatively simple?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two schemes to define the the integral $\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)dP(\omega)$, for $X$ a random variable taking values in a Banach space --- Bochner integral and Pettis integral --- depending on the strong or weak measurability of $X$ respectively.

Click [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral) for Bochner integral, and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pettis_integral) for Pettis integral, both from Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks, seems exactly what I was looking for. I'd prefer the Böchner one, it seems.

Comment: @Mathmath if this answers your question, you should mark it as such. Let's everyone know you are not looking for more input.

Comment: Okay, cool, done, thanks!